# JParallax center layers onload

Tags: jquery

May someone tell me why, in the beautiful JParallax plugin, in the demo online page the layers are center at the first page load.
http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax_demos.html

In the downloaded demo (index.html) they are align at top left, where is the difference?
I want to center them but i cannot do it.
http://trustweb.it/jparallax/demos/index.html

thanks a lot

Comment: do you have a link we can compare it against with? coz center could mean any number of things, and could really depend on different brosers and/or versions of the same browser

Comment: yes i uploaded and linked the default demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.parallax-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

I had the same issue and fixed it with a top and left adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

OK on your second example `"<img class="parallax-layer" />"` is missing the margin, position absolute etc... so either do it manually, or find the right options that shifts all 7 images slightly to the left or something.

Comment: sorry, i am not understanding it, the first example (the working one) i have posted dosen't have any class="parallax-layer" in the html, where is set the layers align property?

Comment: ok i have added class for every image and setted the margin correctly, thanks a lot :)